# How can I get around "this component does not fit the criteria for having an automatically generated guid"

Tags: .net, windows, wix, installation, windows-installer

WiX is complaining (what are the odds, right?):

> Error 95  The component 'blahblah' has a key file with path
>   'TARGETDIR\blah.dll'.  Since this path is not rooted in one of the
>   standard directories (like ProgramFilesFolder), this component does
>   not fit the criteria for having an automatically generated guid. 
>   (This error may also occur if a path contains a likely standard
>   directory such as nesting a directory with name "Common Files" under
>   ProgramFilesFolder.)

But I WANT an automatically generated GUID, and I DON'T want to have to set the TARGETDIR to some other path comprised of ProgramFilesFolder since I am setting the TARGETDIR in the UI and I even allow the user to change it so that people can specify the path they want to install the application at...how does someone get this functionality? Is it possible? I mean, can I have the best of both worlds or not? Why is it such a big deal? WiX is way too restrictive sometimes...

Comment: WiX isn't complaining, Windows Installer is complaining. It's a big deal because the underlying Windows Installer has something called the component rules.  Bad things happen when you break them.

Comment: Then don't use MSI. I understand your frustration... I spent a lot of time fighting MSI when I first learned it.  It's a very rigid framework that doesn't like you coloring outside of the lines.  But once you master it, there is a huge net gain in terms of developer productivity and quality of user experience.

Comment: Unfortunately its a standard that people have come to grips with, otherwise I wouldn't use it :)

Comment: BTW, I misspoke.  That is WiX complaining. I misread the message.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Either way, it doesn't matter who's complaining, what matters is that there was a solution to this all.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328748/harvesting-files-leads-to-lght0231-error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just got it...kind of annoying but its working alright...

I was modifying the TARGETDIR and working with it prior...but now, I realize that I can easily just have worked with INSTALLDIR...for example, I re-factored my directory structure as such:

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
  ...
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="blahFolder" Name="blah">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="blah"/>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

I can get components to reference the INSTALLFOLDER and it will auto-generate GUIDs for them:

```
<ComponentGroup Id='blahgroup'>
    <Component Id='blahId' Directory='INSTALLFOLDER' Transitive='no'>
      <RegistryKey Root='HKLM' Key='Software\blah\blah' ForceCreateOnInstall='no' ForceDeleteOnUninstall='no'>
        <RegistryValue Type='string' Name='blah' Value='BLAH' />
      </RegistryKey>
    </Component>
    ...
</ComponentGroup>
```

But in my UI, its nice because I can modify just the installation folder path quite well:

```
<Product ...>
  ...
  <CustomAction Id='SetInstallFolder' Property='INSTALLFOLDER' Value='[ProgramFilesFolder]blah\blah\'/>
  ...
</Product>
```

I can then force the INSTALLFOLDER to point anywhere I want:

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action='SetInstallFolder' Sequence='1'/>
  ...
</InstallUISequence>
<AdminUISequence>
  <Custom Action='SetInstallFolder' Sequence='1'/>
  ...
</AdminUISequence>
```

Comment: I hope you realize that as authored your custom actions won't fire during silent installation. A bit more logic is required to handle silent installations, repairs and upgrades.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Yeah, I know. Actually, I didn't need to use the actions anymore after I set up the folder structure the way I did. You can see how this was the initial problem. However, beyond that: For quiet installations, MSI packages export public properties, which you can set with the PROPERTY=value syntax on the end of the msiexec parameters. Anyways, I left it in the answer as a exercise/POC so that someone else might benefit from seeing how that may be done.

Answer (score 9):

All you need to do is set Directory/@ComponentGuidGenerationSeed and then you can use auto guids for non-standard folder.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  I now set this on the top folder of my directory hierarchy.

Comment: Um.  How do I do this?

Comment: yeah! Set ComponentGuidGenerationSeed  where - on what directory element? @EdBayiates and to what value (it needs to be set to a GUID according to https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/directory.html). Not even clear if I set this as a parameter to heat or in my Product.wxs

Comment: @lewis example:     <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir" ComponentGuidGenerationSeed="CC245F45-2B96-45DC-9667-A83A75C5D1FE">