# Should I allow heat to generate guids? Getting an error when I try auto-generate during compile because I am not using a standard directory

Tags: msbuild, wix

My first question is, should I work to get the compiler working with auto-generated guids?

I am trying to create an installer for a website with WiX. Please excuse my ignorance, this is my first WiX project. I am following this article:

http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/10/create-an-installer-for-website-with-wix-part-1/

The process uses msbuild to call several WiX tools to ultimately create an MSI. The example uses "Generate guids now" (the "-gg" switch) when calling heat:

```
<Target Name="Harvest">
    <!-- Harvest all content of published result -->
    <Exec
        Command='"$(WiX)bin\heat.exe" dir $(Publish) -dr INSTALLFOLDER -ke -srd -cg MgrWebComponents -var var.publishDir -gg -out $(WebSiteContentCode)'
        ContinueOnError="false"
        WorkingDirectory="." />
</Target>
```

I was reading elsewhere it is best practice to use auto-generated guids (the -ag switch) to ensure product updates install correctly. I notice the guids change every time heat is run.

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="MgrWebComponents">
        <Component Id="cmp56294569B275493319100C26538BA16C" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="{A43DA07B-C4CD-4FE0-AC09-EEA693AB2BA7}">
            <File Id="fil93D55732EC03C2B809F21B9423BF5550" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.publishDir)\BrandImageService.ashx" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="cmp6BD39B2D572EA73C29A81AE5D1C3F0C4" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="{99B7B916-AEC0-4EE9-B17F-E7B325E93A4D}">
            <File Id="filE861424851E26D456D43F5D1855B3E7B" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.publishDir)\Dashboard.aspx" />
        </Component>
...
```

If I should use auto-generated guids I need to get the compiler working. I am getting errors for every file for trying to use auto-generated guids when compiling.

> LGHT0231: The component 'cmp2BE6B5C092821452E1438D39A5110DDB' has a
>   key file  with path 'TARGETDIR\inetpub\manager\tools\toolshome.aspx'. 
>   Since this path  is not rooted in one of the standard directories
>   (like ProgramFilesFolder),  this component does not fit the criteria
>   for having an automatically generated  guid.  (This error may also
>   occur if a path contains a likely standard directory such as nesting a
>   directory with name "Common Files" under ProgramFilesFolder.)

My directory fragment is:

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="INETPUB" Name="Inetpub">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Manager" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

The heat generated fragment looks like:

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="MgrWebComponents">
        <Component Id="cmp56294569B275493319100C26538BA16C" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="*">
            <File Id="fil93D55732EC03C2B809F21B9423BF5550" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.publishDir)\BrandImageService.ashx" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="cmp6BD39B2D572EA73C29A81AE5D1C3F0C4" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filE861424851E26D456D43F5D1855B3E7B" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.publishDir)\Dashboard.aspx" />
        </Component>
...
```

The targets for msbuild:

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <!-- Compile whole solution in release mode -->
    <MSBuild
        Projects="..\Manager.sln"
        Targets="ReBuild"
        Properties="Configuration=Release" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PublishWebsite">
    <!-- Remove complete publish folder in order to 
            be sure that everything will be newly compiled -->
    <Message Text="Removing publish directory: $(SetupF)"/>
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(SetupF)" ContinueOnError="false" />
    <Message Text="Start to publish website" Importance="high" />
    <MSBuild
        Projects="..\\Manager\UI\Manager.UI.csproj"
        Targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication"
        Properties="OutDir=$(Publish)bin\;WebProjectOutputDir=$(Publish);Configuration=Release" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Harvest">
    <!-- Harvest all content of published result -->
    <Exec
        Command='"$(WiX)bin\heat.exe" website $(Publish) -dr INSTALLFOLDER -ke -srd -cg MgrWebComponents -var var.publishDir -ag -out $(WebSiteContentCode)'
        ContinueOnError="false"
        WorkingDirectory="." />
</Target>

<Target Name="WIX">
    <!--     At last create an installer -->
    <Message Text="TEST: @(WixCode)"/>
    <Exec
        Command='"$(WiX)bin\candle.exe" -dpublishDir=$(Publish) -dMgrWebResourceDir=. @(WixCode, &apos; &apos;)'
        ContinueOnError="false"
        WorkingDirectory="." />
    <Exec
        Command='"$(WiX)bin\light.exe" -spdb -out $(MsiOut) @(WixObject, &apos; &apos;)'
        ContinueOnError="false"
        WorkingDirectory="." />

    <!-- A message at the end -->
    <Message Text="Install package has been created." />
</Target>
```

The build command is: `msbuild /t:Build;PublishWebsite;Harvest;WIX setup.build`

I understand the generated guid uses the seed of the directory. Should I change the location of the directory?

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried using the website directive for heat instead of the dir, can't test right now but here's the link http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried that and said it could not find the website. Probably because it is just a directory. I will look more into the website option.

Comment: Did you run the heat website in the Published folder of the WebSite ?

Comment: Yes I believe msbuild is starting a publish after the directory is removed and before heat is run. I added all of the msbuild targets so you can see what it all does.

Comment: can you put your msbuild command line so I go through the targets in the same order as you.   I'll be trying to do the same on one of my tests projects here at work, keep you posted if I find something for you

Comment: Certainly! I added it just below the targets xml. It runs in the same order as it is listed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69770/discussion-between-chegueverra-and-sean).

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328748/harvesting-files-leads-to-lght0231-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you to @CheGueVerra , he pointed me in the right direction. I just changed the directory location to be in ProgramFiles and it was able to compile.

```
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Manager" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
```

Later on I found a better way with the use of the "ComponentGuidGenerationSeed" attribute to keep the directory in the inetpub folder.

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
    <Directory Id="IISMain" Name='inetpub'>
        <Directory Id="WWWMain" Name='wwwroot' 
           ComponentGuidGenerationSeed='{Put-your-own-generated-guid-here}'>
            <Directory Id='INSTALLFOLDER' Name='Manager'>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```