# Wix - what happens if you generate a GUID that already exists on a users machine?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, guid

As part of creating an .msi (An installer program), sometimes one has to generate a unique GUID.  It is hard-coded, and used to uniquely identify the project, or folders (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181501/should-i-allow-heat-to-generate-guids-getting-an-error-when-i-try-auto-generate?rq=1) for an example).

I understand that [when I generate a GUID on my machine](https://winaero.com/generate-new-guid-in-windows-10/), its guaranteed to be unique.  But how can we guarantee it is unique on every computer the program will be installed on?  What happens if you generate a GUID that already exists on the users machine?

Comment: The U means Universal. It's unique in all the known Universe (including Andromeda galaxy). Probably uses the MAC of the machine (that should also be unique)

Comment: *`While the probability that a UUID / GUID will be duplicated is not zero, it is close enough to zero to be negligible`* - [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). What happens if you duplicate an MSI GUID? All kinds of nonsense (it is common to forget to change GUIDs if you should use a new identity for a component GUID or for the product itself for major upgrades). [When to change component GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422121/129130). Note that many GUIDs should remain constant for upgrades - specifically component GUIDs in most trivial cases.